# Computer logs out when resuming from sleep

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, screensaver

When I leave my laptop for a while, after it blacks the screen (as I configured XScreensaver to do), when I return, it awakens to the login screen. When I login, there is no trace of my previous session. If I open Update Manager afterwards and it had been performing and update, it says something about a partially performed update, but doesn't go about updating; it doesn't say broken packages.

This is on clean installs (except for an update manager run) of both Linux Mint 10 LXDE and Lubuntu 10.04 LTS. It didn't happen on Debian LXDE but I hadn't connected that to the internet to do an update.

EDIT:
My `.xsession-errors` , `Xorg.0.log` , and `Xorg.0.log.old` are hosted at [this google docs .zip upload](http://bit.ly/xorg_files) and I'm on a mac right now so I had to mv away the `.` from the beginning of the filenames and I added `.txt` to the ends.

EDIT:
I had a badly stated question without a question mark. My question is:

How can I stop this? Is this a hardware issue? Is this an issue with Ubuntu? X.org?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the logs? ~/.xsession-errors and /var/log/Xorg.n.log may tell you what happened.

Comment: I suspect the X server is crashing. There should be a record of this at the end of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (which will become `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` by the time you log in again). Tell us what you find there. The difference between Ubuntu/Mint and Debian is probably due to slightly different driver versions.

Comment: `XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"` This is an X server or driver bug; could be [#519265](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-180/+bug/519265) or [#346546](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-utils/+bug/346546) or [#738526](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/738526) or any number of other bugs with similar symptoms. Try following [these guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Backtracing) and report a bug to the distribution.

Comment: It even happened when I tried on the Ubuntu LiveCD (while installing the OS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xsession-errors there is an error that is the X Server dying like

```
aborting...
    XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0" after 2926 requests (2824 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

After googling that a bit, your problem seems to be common with ubuntu so it is probably something they have in one of their patches to X. I would log into launchpad and submit a bug report if you are still having the problem (assuming one doesn't already exist)

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I can change to fix it?